# Create a bar chart from a dictionary in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I can't figure out how to create a bar chart with a dictionary in Python 3.x. I've tried searching everywhere, but can't find any help. Here is my code below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dict = {'Monday': Monday/MonCount, 'Tuesday': Tuesday/TueCount, 'Wednesday': Wednesday/WedCount, 'Thursday': Thursday/ThuCount, 'Friday': Friday/FriCount}
plt.bar(dict.keys(),dict.values() , align='center')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Using plt won't work unless you install MatPlotLib, then you would need to follow some of the examples in MatPlotLib docs. Is there another easy way in Python to produce a bar chart? not sure.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that import of Matplotlib. It's still not working and I can't find anything in the matplotlib docs.

Comment: According to its documentation, `pyplot.bar` requires as arguments one array with the bars positions, and one with the bar heights. It is not what you are passing. If you want labels (week days), there is a `tick_label` option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation. If you do what it says, it will work.

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar

*Edit: the link was wrong, sorry.*

You can add the days as labels with the `tick_label` option.